# Automating password entry for enhanced password protection

Tags: windows, automation, keyboard, mouse, clipboard

I want to enter my password which must not be known by me. Therefore I am trying to create a code which would automatically type whatever content is in the clipboard on the first left mouse click and into the place (password-field) where the mouse clicked.

What are the steps I need to follow?

The password field I need to enter my password into does not allow copy pasting directly.

I already have the password generator which copies a password into the clipboard without me knowing it:-   https://github.com/SanTanBan/WhitePassword

Comment: Also, is clipboard content hackproof (during the time any content is within the clipboard)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.